# How to fire the ajax request on error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "recorded-vigil.aspx/GetCameraTimeLineMinutes",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $('.loader').hide();
                    alert('Error in fetching timeline. Please try again');
                    console.log(xhr);
                },
                success: function (results) {
                    $('.loader').hide();
                    $('#spnTimeSelect').html("Please select minute");
                    console.log('GetCameraTimeLineMinutes');

                    if (results != null && results.d != null && results.d.result != null) {
                        var HourSel = $("#MinuteSelect").empty();
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.d.result.length; i++) {
                            var Minute = i;
                            //if (results.d.result[i] == 1)
                            //    HourSel.append('<button class="dayClass activeCam minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</button>');
                            //else
                            //    HourSel.append('<button class="dayClass minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</button>');

                            if (results.d.result[i] == 1)
                                HourSel.append('<div class="btn on minbutton minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</div>');
                            else
                                HourSel.append('<div class="btn minbutton minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</div>');

                            //if (i == 16)
                            //    oSel.append('<hr style="visibility:hidden;"><div id="dayBreak">&nbsp;</div>');
                        }
                        breakMinutes();
                        $('.minuteClass').on('click', onMinuteClick);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This used to throw error because of server timeout. 
Is there any way to fire this again on error. If we try this say 3 times, then we can show the timeout error. Is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying 3 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, then yes this is possible. There are many ways you can achieve this - consider the following adjustments to your code to show how this could be achieved:

```
var retries = 3; // Track the number of retries

function doRequest() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recorded-vigil.aspx/GetCameraTimeLineMinutes",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        error: function (xhr) {
            $('.loader').hide();
            alert('Error in fetching timeline. Please try again');
            console.log(xhr);

            retries--; // Decrement the number of remaining retries

            if(retries >= 0) { // If more retries available, fire another request
                doRequest()
            }
        },
        success: function (results) {

            retries = 3; // Optional reset if you want to do this also

            $('.loader').hide();
            $('#spnTimeSelect').html("Please select minute");
            console.log('GetCameraTimeLineMinutes');

            if (results != null && results.d != null && results.d.result != null) {
                var HourSel = $("#MinuteSelect").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < results.d.result.length; i++) {
                    var Minute = i;
                    //if (results.d.result[i] == 1)
                    //    HourSel.append('<button class="dayClass activeCam minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</button>');
                    //else
                    //    HourSel.append('<button class="dayClass minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</button>');

                    if (results.d.result[i] == 1)
                        HourSel.append('<div class="btn on minbutton minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</div>');
                    else
                        HourSel.append('<div class="btn minbutton minuteClass" data-minuteindex="' + Minute + '">' + Minute + '</div>');

                    //if (i == 16)
                    //    oSel.append('<hr style="visibility:hidden;"><div id="dayBreak">&nbsp;</div>');
                }
                breakMinutes();
                $('.minuteClass').on('click', onMinuteClick);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Agreed, and you can reset 'retries' on success()